# How to convert custom css into bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a code for the right slide navigation bar menu in custom CSS which works great but now I am looking for the code to include bootstrap so that it would be responsive in nature. Currently, the menu is not responsive and only viewable on desktop not on mobile. Can anyone help to give an input?

**html menu:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<header>
    <span class="toggle-button">
        <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-top"></div>
        <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-middle"></div>
        <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-bottom"></div>
    </span>
    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <div class="menu-sidebar">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="children"><a href="#">News</a>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                    <ul class="child-menu ">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="children"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                    <ul class="child-menu ">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="children"><a href="#">About</a>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                    <ul class="child-menu ">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>

            </ul>           
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
    <section class="text">
        <h2 class="heading">Three Line Menu & CSS Transitions</h2>

        <p class="buttons" style="margin-left: 140px;">
              <a href="#" class="btn_one">Learn More</a>

        </p>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {


        background: url(https://s33.postimg.cc/tm1vd9yy7/Background_2.jpg);
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;  

     }

.btn_one {

text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-weight: 100;
border: 1px #fbbc05 solid;
padding: 1em 3em;
border-radius: 100px;   
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
list-style: none;
}
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, serif;
}
::selection {
background-color: #EBEBF2;
color: #83828D;
 }


/* ==================================== */
  /*      Navigaton Menu        */
/* ==================================== */

.menu-wrap {
 background-color: #625871;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 280px;
margin-left: -280px;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: 700;
overflow: auto;
transition: .25s;
z-index: 10;
}
.menu-show {
margin-left: 0;
box-shadow: 4px 2px 15px 1px #262424;
}



.menu-sidebar {
margin: 75px 0 80px 10px;
position: relative;
top: 70px;
}
.menu-sidebar li {
padding: 18px 22px 0;
}
.menu-sidebar li > a {
color: #f3f3f3;
font-size: 1.18em;
position: relative;
}
.menu-sidebar li > a::after {
content: "";
display: block;
height: 0.15em;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
width: 100%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50.3%, #FFFA3B 50.3%);
transition: background-position .2s .1s ease-out;
background-size: 200% auto;
}
.menu-sidebar li > a:hover::after {
background-position: -100% 0;
}
.menu-sidebar .children {
position: relative;
}
.menu-sidebar .children .child-menu {
display: none;
}
.arrow::after {
content: "\f107";
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
padding: 10px;
color: #FFFA3B;
position: relative;
}
.arrow:hover::after {
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
}
.arrow:active::after {
top: 2px;
}


 /*Hamburger Button*/
.toggle-button {
position: fixed;
width: 44px;
height: 40px;
top: 50px;
left: 40px;
padding: 4px;
transition: .25s;
z-index: 15;
}
.toggle-button:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-button .menu-bar {
position: absolute;
border-radius: 2px; 
transition: .5s;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar-top {
border: 4px solid #fff;
border-bottom: none;
top: 0;
width: 80%;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar-middle {
height: 4px;
background-color: #fff;
margin-top: 7px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
width: 40%;
top: 4px;
}
.toggle-button .menu-bar-bottom {
border: 4px solid #fff;
border-top: none;
top: 22px;
width: 60%;
}
.toggle-button:hover div 
{
width: 80%;
}




.button-open {
left: 25px;
}
.button-open .menu-bar-top {
border-color: #fff;
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 8px);
transition: .5s;
}
.button-open .menu-bar-middle {
background-color: #fff;
transform: translate(230px);
transition: .1s ease-in;
opacity: 0;
}
.button-open .menu-bar-bottom {
border-color: #fff;
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -7px);
transition: .5s;
}



/* Text Block */
.wrapper {
width: 40%;
margin: 100px auto 0;
color: #83828D;
 }
.wrapper .text {
padding: 30px;
 }
.wrapper .text .heading {
margin-bottom: 40px;
font-size: 2em;
color:#fff;
  }
 .wrapper .text p {
line-height: 1.6em;
  }
  .wrapper .text .buttons {
margin-top: 40px;
  }

/* Buttons */
.wrapper .buttons .button {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
padding: 20px 25px;
border-radius: 2em;
background-color: #70CE64;
color: #fff;
font-size: .9em;
font-weight: 700;
transition: background-color .3s;
  }
 .wrapper .buttons .button-secondary {
background-color: #FF6746;
  }
 .wrapper .buttons .button-primary:hover {
 background-color: #84D07A;
  }
  .wrapper .buttons .button-secondary:hover {
  background-color: #FF7D60;
 }

  /*Active state for the buttons*/

    .wrapper .buttons .button-primary:active {
      background-color: #70CE64;
  }
   .wrapper .buttons .button-secondary:active {
      background-color: #FF6746;
   }

/*Icons*/
.wrapper .buttons .button span {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 20px;
}
.wrapper .buttons .button span::after {
position: absolute;
font-family: "FontAwesome";
right: -3px;
font-size: 14px;
top: 0;
transition: top .3s, right .3s;
}
.wrapper .buttons .button-primary span::after {
content: "\f019";
  }
 .wrapper .buttons .button-secondary span::after {
content: "\f178";
 }
  /*Slight icons animation*/
    .wrapper .buttons .button-primary:hover span::after {
    top: 4px;
     }
  .wrapper .buttons .button-secondary:hover span::after {
right: -6px;
 }
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $toggleButton = $('.toggle-button'),
    $menuWrap = $('.menu-wrap'),
    $sidebarArrow = $('.arrow');

// Hamburger button

$toggleButton.on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('button-open');
    $menuWrap.toggleClass('menu-show');
});

// Sidebar navigation arrows

$sidebarArrow.click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

});
```

**HERE IS DEMO:** https://app.clickfunnels.com/for_domain/businesswealthcoach.clickfunnels.com/optin?updated_at=50ad6cd4f6bfdb311282b75af59e07c1v2&track=0&preview=true

**HERE IS SOURCE CODE:**https://www.nofile.io/f/TUDPjOzrhBQ/source_code.zip

Any input is appreciated.
Thank you so much.

Comment: You don't have to use Bootstrap to make it responsive.

Comment: so what would I do? sorry I am new in web development

Comment: You can't... "convert custom css into bootstrap". Bootstrap is a css library which you can utilize but you shouldn't be modifying it in any way. You can extend bootstrap by using custom css. Bootstrap is just a bunch of predefined css classes which you can use in your code. Here someone asked similar question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246728/custom-css-in-bootstrap-theme

Comment: I would suggest learning about responsive layouts and then apply what you have learnt to your specific situation

Answer (score 0):

This question is not related to bootstrap. Your css only works on a specific screen width. 
You can change your css like below to get your expected result. If you want to flexibility of bootstrap you should avoid static lengths.

```
.menu-show {
    margin-left: 0px;
    box-shadow: 4px 2px 15px 1px #262424;
}
.menu-wrap {
    background-color: #625871;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: -280px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: .25s;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2gnhxyt1/6/

Comment: thanks for the answer but above property is not working

Comment: could you simplify your code and share a fiddle link? This seems working on chrome. You might have missed "left: 0;"

Comment: here is js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/navjot789/2gnhxyt1/    but its seems its not work!   here is the full source code zip file sir :https://nofile.io/f/TUDPjOzrhBQ/source_code.zip

Comment: it would be a great help you do that for me thankyou so much

Comment: You have forgot left:0 as i mentioned. I have added that and jquery cdn. Now it looks fine. https://jsfiddle.net/2gnhxyt1/6/